# When should I use 9 patch image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

Please help me to understand on when i have to make decision to define 9 patch image. what i have understood is, 9-patch image is require only when i have defined my layout width and height with definite size but actually i don't have image of that size. let's say, i have set background size as 300*100 in my layout definition. but image i have 200*100, which is lesser size then what i need. in this case if i do define 9 patch image, will help to fit properly without compressing quality in all devices.

This where i used to 9 patch.

Now, what i want to understand is, does 9 patch image will scales on different screen resolution even if i have defined our layout definition as wrap content, match parent with no explicit value on width and height. does 9-patch will scale based on screen resolution?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html , its just act as normal image where based on parents request it will be in same or expanded size.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 7):

**What are exactly nine patch -**
The 9-Patch is a modified PNG image that allows Android to determine how the image can be stretched to meet the specific layout during runtime(like fill_parent and wrap_content).

**Common Usege -**
 1. Button backgrounds. (Default Android gray Button is a Nine-Patch)
 2. Page backgrounds.
 3. Splash screens.

**Step-by-Step guides-**
1. Edit NinePatch in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).
2. Best practice design usage [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Drawables#creating-a-layer-list).